# How do I connect to the emulator under the virtual machine

Tags: windows, macos, react-native, virtual-machine, vmware

I am using windows operating system, but my computer has a mac installed on the virtual machine. How can I connect to xcode's emulator on mac from windows?
Thank you.

Comment: what u mean run the code from outside the virtual machine ?

Comment: When I run the code on windows, the host operating system, I want the ios emulator on MacOs to run.